# How do I get Coco?

Tags: animal-crossing-wild-world

I want Coco to move to my town. Is there any way I can make her come? I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the only way to get villagers to move to your town in Wild World other than by random chance is to talk to them while visiting other towns and have the other player on your Friends List. If you talk to them you might end up encouraging them to move to your town in the future. This is not guaranteed, but it is your best bet.

As for visiting other towns, you can only do this at this time by finding another local player and visiting their town over system-to-system connection between the games as the Nintendo WFC service has been shut down for the DS (meaning, no Internet play).

I hope this helps.